# Single Photon Counting Module

Tags: experimental-physics, photons

I have a single photon counting module from Picoquant (tau-SPAD) . When it is powered on, the TTL output  has a constant value of around 4 volts (as opposed to occasional TTL spikes indicating photon incidences) . So basically it is not giving any photon counts at all. Can anyone help me figure out why this might be happening and what this means.

Comment: First, RTFM.  Then, at the very least, let us know how you built your dark-box or equivalent.  How do you know you aren't permanently saturating the detector?

Comment: The detector is coupled to light through a single-mode fiber. The setup is completely dark with only down-converted photons passing through the fiber. Another detector subject to the same light gives proper counts, therefore the detector could not have been permanently saturated, I believe.

Comment: Check whether the o/p is open collector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector